# Why the Survey Corps doesn't find a human body inside normal titan?

Tags: attack-on-titan

Hange cut the neck of one titan to explore inside. Why couldn't she find out the main human body inside???

Maybe the main body was hidden quite deep so it was difficult to see. But if it was hidden quite deep, then how can Levi and other soldiers cut down the neck and kill the titan.

Is this a logical flaw in AOT?

Comment: "Why couldn't she find out the main human body inside?" Where did you get this from? When the survey corps learn about the nature of titans in the manga, they do realize why they can kill them by slashing their napes.

Answer (score 2):

The titans you are talking about are generic titans, which are different from Shape-shifting titans. Generic titans transformed permanently into titans. Their human bodies no longer exist. They can't transform back into humans. If you cut their nape, they are dead, once and for all.

This is different than titan shifters such Eren, because when they transform, they build a titan body around their human body. The human body acts as a center of control for the titan body. They can *power down*, whenever they want. They have inherited the Titan shifting power. That's why, if you cut the nape of a shifter, you'll find the human sitting there. And until you hurt/kill that human, they can transform again.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense when put together with Yuri's transformation. In your scenario her body would not exist at the point when she eats Marcel. So where would it come from?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a flaw and explained in later chapters. I will give a spoilered explanation, exhibiting SOME of the information. A full disclosure would take much of the fun out of AOT in my opinion.

> A "normal" titan (i.e. any titan except for Eren's, the giant one and the amored one up to this point) doesn't have a human in the neck, though it is its weakpoint. At most it will have one or more in its stomach. The other three titans do have a human in the neck each. Which titans have a human in the neck will be explained later. Where titans come from will be explained. But that is all major spoiler material. Please ask a different question if you want answers to these major spoilers.

Comment: You can provide major spoilers within your answer, as long you use the spoiler tags (which you have used). That’s why it’s there :)

Comment: @Wondercricket I just thought, there are spoilers, and major spoilers (like e.g. for Code Geass) AND there's AoT. I feel morally bound not to spoiler too much. AoT is a gift to humanity <3 My fanboying comes from the fact that after years and years of manga, AoT was the first that could surprise me with almost every chapter without suspending my believe ;)

Comment: Firstly, i have already read 105 chaps in AOT.Secondly, the MAIN human bodies means that the bodies of the Eldians in the land not island stick into the titan's body, under the nape, and they are both unconcious but not really dead (unlike the shifter titans, Eren and other guys can control their titans). All the titans (including the shifter titans) have the same weakpoint - the human in their neck, it means each normal titan has the person under its nape (who not be eaten by titan) like the shifter titans. I wonder why Hange couldn't find out the Eldians people in the neck of the titans.

Comment: @NguyễnQuỳnhThủyTrúc Because they are not there, Eldians usually get fully transformed, as far as I'm aware

Comment: How can the human body come back from not being there when they eat a Shifter Titan, like Yuri did with Marcel after many years as a Pure Titan?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of Titan. "Generic Titan" (including abnormal types) and shapeshifter Titan (humans who can transform into Titan.

The ones with humans inside are the Titan shifters, like Eren.

The ones without humans inside are the generic Titans.

> Generic Titans are actually humans that have been injected with Titan serum, turning them into Titans. They don't have humans inside because their whole body turned into a Titan. Which is why, if their nape was cut, they die.

Comment: If they didn't have a human in the nape, why is the nape a spot of vulnerability? And where did Yuri's human body come from after eating Marcel when she'd been a pure titan for decades?